# list subdirectory with some naming conversion

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, find

I want to write a script that will run a certain commands on my subdirectories with names containging or rather end with some strings, say, `*-nom1`, `*-nom2`, `*-nom3`. i.e.

```
for dir in $(subs)
do
   // do something in this dir
done
```

my question is, would this be the way to list my sub-directories, if not what's the best way to do it:

```
subs = find -maxdepth 2 -type d -name '*-nom1'
&& find -maxdepth 2 -type d -name '*-nom2' 
&& find -maxdepth 2 -type d -name '*-nom3'
```

I can test it on my `Ubuntu` terminal and it seems to work.

my script will be running on `Debian` if that helps.

Comment: Do you care about the order in which you traverse the directories? Why not just `for dir in */*-nom[123]`? What does the directory tree structure look like?

Comment: `nom1`, `nom2`, `nom3` are just examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things I can think of

1. Combine three `find` invocations into one

   ```
   find -maxdepth 2 -type d \( -name '*-nom1' -o -name '*-nom2' -o -name '*-nom3' \)
   ```
2. Use `find`'s ability to execute commands to avoid the external `for` loop

   ```
   find -maxdepth 2 -type d \( -name '*-nom1' -o -name '*-nom2' -o -name '*-nom3' \) \
   -exec sh -c 'for d; do cd "$d"; cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; ...; done' sh {} +
   ```

Comment: hi @iruvar what are `sh -c` and `sh +` do? `do echo "$d"` just output +

Comment: @rm, oops, see correction. `sh -c` spawns off a shell to which qualifying files are fed

Answer (score 1):

You can combine tests in `find` with `-o` standing for "or"; the implicit operator between tests is "and". For example:

```
subs="$(find -maxdepth 2 -type d \( \
  -name "*-nom1" -o -name "*-nom2" -o -name "*-nom3" \
\) )"
for d in $subs ; do
  ... do something with "$d" ...
done
```

The parantheses around `-name "*-nom1" -o -name "*-nom2" -o "*-nom3" need to be quoted because they are reserved words for the shell.

Now, as don_crissti remarks in a comment, the general recommendation is to avoid capturing the output of `find`, for two reasons; first, because file names may contain spaces and newlines and special characters and son on; and second, because `find` by its very nature loops over the results. The better idiom is to use the implicit loop in `find`; see [*Why is looping over find's output bad practice*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice) and the associated discussion:

```
find -maxdepth 2 -type d \( \
  -name "*-nom1" -o -name "*-nom2" -o -name "*-nom3" \
\) -exec \
  ... do something with '{}' ...
\;
```

Comment: Right. I will ammend the answer to include a brief explanation.

Comment: hi @AlexP, I would like to generate a new directory using the last part of the directory. i.e. `basename {}`. doing this seems not to work `$pwd\somdir\basename {}`

Comment: "Generate" is an ambiguous word. Do you want to make a new directory? Where? Directories are made by `mkdir`.

Comment: sorry for being ambiguous. To be specific i need to run `dotnet publish` (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-publish), specifying the `--output` directory as `$pwd/publish/(basename {})`. the command will create the output directory if it doesn't exist. i.e. `dotnet publish {} -configuration release --output $pwd/publish/(basename {})`

Comment: `MakeDirIfNotExisting () { [ -d "./publish/$(basename "$1")" ] || mkdir "./publish/$(basename "$1")" ; }`

Comment: i meant i don't need to `mkdir` the directory. I just need to specify it, and `dotnet` command will create it if it doesn't exists.